# What's wrong with my glob?

Tags: javascript, node.js, glob

I'm trying to write a glob for something that uses `minimatch` and having trouble excluding the files I want to. Here's a test case:

```
const glob = 'src/js/*!(test|stub).js' // this is the glob I'm trying to work out

const shouldMatch = [
  'src/js/foo.js',
  'src/js/bar.js',
  'src/js/baz.js',
]

const shouldNotMatch = [
  'src/js/foo.test.js',
  'src/js/bar.stub.js',
  'src/baz/blob.js',
]

const all = shouldMatch.concat(shouldNotMatch)

const matched = minimatch.match(all, glob) // https://www.npmjs.com/package/minimatch

expect(matched).toEqual(shouldMatch) // https://npmjs.com/package/expect
```

The output with this is:

```
"Error: Expected [ 'src/js/foo.js', 'src/js/bar.js', 'src/js/baz.js', 'src/js/foo.test.js', 'src/js/bar.stub.js' ] to equal [ 'src/js/foo.js', 'src/js/bar.js', 'src/js/baz.js' ]
```

You can see a live version of this [here](https://jsbin.com/qavupu/edit?js,console).

As you can see, it's including both the `test` and the `stub` files. **What does my glob need to be so those files are excluded?**

Comment: your glob is a string not a regular expression

Comment: const glob = 'src/js/*(foo|bar|baz).js'

is their any problem in trying this regex? apart from the fact that it can be very long!

Comment: Yeah, this is an isolated example to make solving the core problem simpler. In reality I have a lot more files (and will add more overtime). I really need to get this working as coded. Also, I'm passing the glob to a third party, so I can't use a regex, it has to be a genuine glob.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a common mistake with the `!(...)` syntax. Imagine something like this:

`ls *!(.png|.jpg)`

This doesn't do what we want because the `.png` and `.jpg` are matched by the `*`. So once we get to `!(.png|.jpg)`, the string is null.

To fix it, we can do:

`ls !(*.png|*.jpg)`

Thus, to fix your example:

`const glob = 'src/js/!(*test|*stub).js'`

Here's [a working example](https://jsbin.com/pulacav/edit?js,console)

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you Chris!